# Wireless networking is faster when lid is open than closed?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I like to connect my laptop to an external monitor and close my laptop's lid. However, I noticed something. According to internet speedtests (and my personal knowledge from downloading large files), my wireless networking speed is nearly 10X faster when my lid is open than when my lid is closed (or more!). How do I make it so my speed is just as fast when the lid is closed?

NOTE:
In an internet speed test with the lid open I got about **20** Mbps down.
In an internet speed test with the lid closed I got about **2** Mbps down.

NOTE:
I am using a Gateway NE56R41u if that helps. **The Gateway NE56R41u is not Ubuntu certified. It has a Broadcom BCM4313.**

Comment: Have you checked if your wlan signal is worse with closed lid?

Comment: I haven't and I am unable to test.

Comment: Unless wlan is my wireless adapter. Then I DO know that it is slower with the lid closed.

Comment: I just realized that I am using a proprietary driver for the wireless adapter.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: @WildMan You can see the results with my lid closed at https://www.dropbox.com/s/stl8n1gtywzirg1/wireless-info.txt?dl=1

Comment: Is there another driver I can use?

Comment: Let's start by adding the best driver which is brcmsmac, do `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` Then `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` put a # in front of `#blacklist bcma` and a # infront of `#blacklist  brcmsmac` then save and close gedit and reboot. Then post another file from the script using the new driver if that does not fix your issue.

Comment: I did not see either of those entries in the file. Please help me install that driver.

Comment: I am away from my house and my laptop is barely working at the moment so I am going be slow to reply. That driver is apart of the kernel so we do not need to install it just unblacklist it as per the instructons above, I will make sure that is the correct file because there is more then one.

Comment: Those drivers are in these two files: `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf` and `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf` it is possible that the purge command will remove them from the file sometimes it does so they may not still be there. After you are done with the blacklist file reboot, and if wireless do not come on do `sudo modprobe brcmsmac` and post a new file.

Comment: @WildMan You were right! I was able to get that driver working! I then ran speed tests and showed that the more closed my laptop's lid is the slower the connection is, gradually. I think that means that it was obstructions or signal problems causing my problems and not the driver. However, I will keep using the brcmsmac driver anyway because I like free and open-source software and I will be less likely to have problems in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Case closed. I'll move my desk to the other side of my office to get better signal.

Comment: I am on my cell when i get to internet connection i Will write up the answer if you post a new file i will look and see if there are any parameters we can set with that driver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The antenna for the wireless in your laptop is probably in the screen. I have noticed that the connection on my laptop is slightly slower with the lid shut but by nowhere near the amount you describe.

Comment: This is due to the antenna, and if you have studied antenna, you will know the antenna forward power, reverse power, and directional power. Laptop's design usually have its antenna install at the screen, most, vertically upwards.

You can try this: Tilt your gateway to 90 degrees and see if it'll help. I usually did mine like that whenever I close my laptop lid while use an external screen. It might help a little.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable power saving for you wifi adapter with:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

To make the change persistent after reboots:

`cd /etc/pm/power.d` then `sudo nano wifi_pwr_off` this will create a new file, paste:

```
#!/bin/sh 
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Save the file and run `sudo chmod +x wifi_pwr_off` to make it executable.

Comment: What does all of this do exactly?

Comment: Also, you didn't put hoe to save the file. I don't use nano very much.

Comment: Nano will display how you save the file, it is `crtl + o` you can use any editor you prefer.

Comment: @Pabi  ctrl-o, not ctrl-0

Comment: Corrected the typo.

Comment: So, it says wlan0 power off. What is wlan0, my Ethernet port or wireless adapter? Why would I want to turn it off?

Comment: `wlan0` is your wlan adpater. As is wrote abve this will turn off power saving not the wlan0 adapter.

Comment: Oh. That makes so much sense now. I will try it right now.

Comment: That did not fix the problem. Hopefully some one else will answer.

Comment: It probably is a power saving issue, there is usually depending on the driver a parameter that can be set to turn it off but I am preparing to leave town and do not have the time to help but hopefully someone else will drop in.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, your antenna is probably around the screen, 
so when you close the lid, you have rotated it 90 degrees, and may
have degraded the signal.  With the screen open, find the signal
strength with:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0
```

Do this with the laptop turned in several directions and see if the
quality/strength of the signal varies. (Probably highest with the 
screen perpendicular to the router).
  Now, close the lid, and put the laptop in a plastic rack or
plate holder (or someplace stable so it doesn't fall) with the
same orientation as the screen when the signal was maximum.
Does this help?  If not, turn the laptop completely around, 
the bottom may block the signal.  Any luck?
  Now, if you find some improvement, think about changing the
router's antenna (if you are not concerned with any other devices
on your network which you might degrade).  Most antennas may be 
tilted and turned, so maybe laying it flat instead of upright
may improve the closed laptop signal (when sitting normally, not
on edge).
  Since the bottom of the laptop may interfer, nothing may help much
unless you are willing to modify the laptop for an external antenna.